# How to exclude grails plugin jar from war file

Tags: grails, gradle, build, war

Grails 3.2.5.  Build.gradle has mail plugin:

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC6"
```

In deploying a war to production I need to remove javax.mail-1.5.6.jar from WEB-INF/lib since that jar must be in the Tomcat lib when using a JNDI mail resource.  So how do I keep the mail plugin but remove the offending jar file from the war?  I knew how to do this in Grails 2.x.  Via the gradle war task in build.gradle I have tried to exclude the file (doesn't work - the jar drifts in from a plugin somehow), and have tried to filter the file out.  When I build the war I get two files - "app-0.1.war" and "app-0.1.war.original".  The "original" file has the WEB-INF/lib/javax.mail jar filtered out, but the real, complete war still has it.

So how do I prevent that plugin jar from getting into the war file?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is with something like this:

```
war {
    rootSpec.exclude '**/javax.mail*.jar'
}
```

(you may need to adjust depending on whether or not you want to also exclude the `javax.mail-api` jar file along with the `javax.mail` jar)

See https://github.com/jeffbrown/excludejar/blob/67734ac0c65cdbead468f1e65bcfc29041cd2279/build.gradle#L70-L72

Comment: Ah, my problem seems to be that "grails war" (i.e. "grails assemble") adds the bootRepackage and assemble tasks.  These actions ignore the rootSpec.exclude action for the libs since it is building a runnable jar (war).  For Tomcat deployment it looks like I need to execute "gradle war", or just use the "original" version of the war created by the "grails assemble" command.

Comment: I would use `gradlew assemble`.  If the `war` Gradle plugin is installed then the `assemble` task creates a `.war` file otherwise it creates an executable `.jar` file.  As I switch back and forth between projects I don't have to remember which ones use a `.war` and which one uses a `.jar`.  I just run `assemble` and the right thing happens.

Comment: If you run `./gradlew assemble` in the project I linked in the answer above, you will see that it works.